# Sumar minutos a hora actual con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

tengo un número al azar que es 95, este número se lo quiero sumar a la hora actual y quiero que solo sume 60 minutos y los otros 35 (este número puede ser dinámico) se los sume a la siguiente hora, es un cálculo de hora lo que necesito, tengo un código el cual me está funcionando pero me está retornando todo lo que es: **Nombre del dia de la semana, día del mes, año y la hora completa con milisegundos**, necesito tomar de este valor, **SOLAMENTE LA HORA Y LOS MINUTOS**, acá les dejo el código que tengo:

```js
Date.prototype.addMins = function(m) {     
    this.setTime(this.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
    return this;    
} 

function calcularHora(e) {
    let numeroalazar = 95
    let fecha = new Date();

    console.log(fecha.addMins(numeroalazar));
  }
  
  calcularHora();
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es formatear el resultado, la suma se hace correctamente

Comment: Así es, es correcto lo que dices

Answer (score 0):

Usando el objeto `Intl.DateTimeFormat`:

```js
Date.prototype.addMins = function(m) {     
    this.setTime(this.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
    return this;    
} 

function calcularHora(e) {
    let numeroalazar = 95
    let fecha = new Date();
    let formateador = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("es-ES",{hour:'numeric',minute:'numeric'});

    console.log( formateador.format( fecha.addMins(numeroalazar)) );
}
  
calcularHora();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dado que estás utilizando prototipos para añadir tus funciones, podrías añadir tu propia función para devolver el formato esperando de la hora, o bien, crear una función más genérica (`getFormattedDate(format)`) y pasarle una cadena o expresión que indique el formato de lo que quieres devolver, por ejemplo: `hh:mm`, `hh:mm:ss`, etc.

Para el caso de tu pregunta, podría quedar así:

```js
Date.prototype.addMins = function(minsToAdd) {     
  this.setTime(this.getTime() + (minsToAdd * 60 * 1000));
  return this;    
} 

Date.prototype.getHHMMFormat = function() {
  const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es-ES', {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric'
  });
  return formatter.format(this.getTime());
}
  
let d = new Date();
let randomNumber = 95;
d.addMins(randomNumber);
console.log('Hora final: ', d.getHHMMFormat());
```

Espero que te sirva y ayude. Si tienes dudas, puedes utilizar los comentarios.